# Creating a Java Object for a json file where Keys are always different

Tags: java, json, class, object, gson

The .json files look something like this

**XYZ.json**

```
{
"Business Information": {
    "xpath": "//span[text()='Business Information']",
    "elementType": "LINK",
    "findBy": "XPath"
},
"AP and Ship-To Information": {
    "xpath": "//span[text()='AP and Ship-To Information']",
    "elementType": "LINK",
    "findBy": "XPath"
},
"Other Business Details": {
    "xpath": "//span[text()='Other Business Details']",
    "elementType": "LINK",
    "findBy": "XPath"
},
"Bank and Trade Information": {
    "xpath": "//span[text()='Bank and Trade Information']",
    "elementType": "LINK",
    "findBy": "XPath"
}
}
```

I want to create a Java Object where I can store these keys. But the problem is that there are 100s of different keys. Creating an object for nested elements is easy.

**Tabs.class**

```
public class Tabs {
    private String xpath;
    private String elementType;
    private String findBy;
}
```

But for the class TabNames...

**TabNames.class**

```
public class TabNames {
    Tab Business Name; // Cannot create Object with whitespace
    Tab 2;
    Tab 3;
    and so on.. // there maybe 100s of tabs from JSON
```

Configuring an object like this would be impossible and simply stupid. Can anyone provide an alternative or better solution to the problem ?

Comment: are you able to modify the layout / structure of the JSON file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HashMap` for this, for example:

```
HashMap<String, Tabs> myTabs = new HashMap<>();
myTabs.put("Business Information", new Tabs());
```

Here you would replace `new Tabs()` with your parsed `Tabs` class, and you would change `"Business Information"` to the key associated with the `Tabs` class. This can be done in a for loop by iterating over your JSON object.

You can get your `Tabs` objects afterwards based on the `Key` value of the `HashMap`:

```
Tabs tab = myTabs.get("Business Information");
```

Comment: How would I store the Key in an object and preserve the formatting when writing that object later to a similar .json file?

Comment: GSON will automatically parse `HashMap` objects into the correct JSON format

Answer (score 0):

instead of a structure like

```
{
"Business Information": {
    "xpath": "//span[text()='Business Information']",
    "elementType": "LINK",
    "findBy": "XPath"
},
```

I recommend this:

```
[
    {
        "type": "tab",
        "name": "Business Information",
        "xpath": "//span[text()='Business Information']",
        "elementType": "LINK",
        "findBy": "XPath"
    }, {
        "type": "tab",
        "name": "Business Information",
        "xpath": "//span[text()='Business Information']",
        "elementType": "LINK",
        "findBy": "XPath"
    }, ...

]
```

Now you can easily iterate over the JSON Array and each of the members is an object of class "tabs.class". Properties do not have any space and thus can be used directly.

Comment: This would be a perfect solution, but the .json formatting comes from a private framework which would need to be modified wholly.